# Flink or Spark for incremental data

Tags: java, apache-spark, batch-processing, apache-flink, stream-processing

I have no experience with either `Flink` or `Spark`, and I would like to use one of them for my use case. I'd like to present my use case and hopefully get some insight of whether this can be done with either, and if they can both do that, which one would work best.

I have a bunch of entities `A` stored in a data store (Mongo to be precise but it doesn't matter really). I have a Java application that can load these entities and **run some logic** on them to generate a Stream of some data type `E` (to be 100% clear I don't have the `Es` in any data set, I need to generate them in Java after I load the `As` from the DB)

So I have something like this

```
A1 -> Stream<E>
A2 -> Stream<E>
...
An -> Stream<E>
```

The data type `E` is a bit like a long row in Excel, it has a bunch of columns. I need to collect all the `Es` and run some sort of pivot aggregation like you would do in Excel. I can see how I could do that easily in either `Spark` or `Flink`.

**Now is the part I cannot figure out.**

Imagine that one of the entity `A1` is changed (by a user or a process), that mean that all the `Es` for `A1` need updating. Of course I could reload all my `As`, recompute all the `Es`, and then re-run the whole aggregation. By I'm wondering if it's possible to be a bit more clever here.

Would it be possible to only recompute the `Es` for `A1` and do the minimum amount of processing.

For `Spark` would it be possible to persist the `RDD` and only update part of it when needed (here that would be the `Es` for `A1`)?

For `Flink`, in the case of streaming, is it possible to update data points that have already been processed? Can it handle that sort of case? Or could I perhaps generate *negative* events for `A1`'s old `Es` (i.e that would remove them from the result) and then add the new ones?

Is that a common use case? Is that even something that `Flink` or `Spark` are designed to do? I would think so but again I haven't used either so my understanding is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is very broad and depends on many conditions. In flink you could have a `MapState<A, E>` and only update the values for the changed `A's` and then depending on your use-case either generate the updated `E's` downstream or generate the difference (retraction stream).

In Flink there exists the concept of **Dynamics Tables** and **Retraction streams** that may inspire you, or maybe event the Table API already covers your use case. You can check out the docs [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/table/streaming.html#streaming-concepts)

Comment: I kept the question broad trying to capture the essence of the problem. You say the answer depends on many conditions. What aspects of the question would you like me to expand on?